# Correct syntax for fulltext search on multiple columns and multiple LIKE's

Tags: sql, full-text-search

I am trying to get this query right

```
foreach(explode(" ", trim($words) ) as $word) $where[] = "LIKE '%$word%'";
$wheresql = implode(" OR ", $where);
$q  = "SELECT item_id, name, price, details, img FROM items WHERE (details $wheresql) OR (name $wheresql) OR (description $wheresql)";
$rows = $this->dba->rawSelect($q);
```

**The query looks like this now**

```
SELECT item_id, name, price, details, img 
FROM items 
WHERE (details LIKE '%someword%' OR LIKE '%someword%') 
   OR (name LIKE '%someword%' OR LIKE '%someword%') 
   OR (description LIKE '%someword%' OR LIKE '%someword%')
```

I am not sure if I have to specify the column for every `LIKE` or do something else

thanks, Richard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach(explode(" ", trim($words) ) as $word) $where[] = "LIKE '%$word%'";
$q = "SELECT item_id, name, price, details, img FROM items WHERE (details ".implode(" OR  details ",$where).") OR (name ".implode(" OR names ",$where).") OR (description ".implode(" OR description ",$where).")";
$rows = $this->dba->rawSelect($q);
```

Comment: thanks, I did it a little differently, by running an outside loop with the column names and put the columnname in the "wheresql".

Comment: @Richard Well the good thing of my SQL statement is that you can use one `$where` and use it in as many columns as you want...

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to specify the column for every LIKE. BTW, why not just have a try running the sql? it will tell you everything.

Comment: I only get error near line...not very helpfull, I know it was a simple question, but it was helpfull, I usually come up with difficult stuff myself, and find out later it could be much simpler